# Telerik RadChart Control - Data is not displayed near the edges of the chart

Tags: c#, wpf, telerik, radchart

I'm working on a WPF application and using the Telerik RadChart control.

I'm having the following issue:

[image]

The number is not displayed for the first and last columns/series.

When I have less columns, everything works great, as in the following image:
[image]

I'm not sure what causes that, and really hope to get any suggestions (maybe its a lack of space, but I'm not sure how to solve that). Thanks!

Comment: have tried setting the Padding property in the XAML of the RadChart control?

Comment: setting the chart's MinHeight property (with a scrollviewer) solved this issue for me.